# EXC_BREAKPOINT: Message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, dealloc

I get the above message in XCode 4.6.  I've done a pretty thorough search and but nothing seems to match the exact circumstances surrounding my issue.  Admittedly, I'm relatively new to iOS dev, and memory-management has never been my strong suit, but this just has me completely miffed.

I have an instance variable `theLink` which is defined in the class `Game` as follows:

```
@interface Game : NSObject

// Class objects
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *queryItems;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *theArray;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *theLink;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *thePath;
```

`theLink` is set in the `makeGame` method which is called in the method `initialiseGame` in my view controller:

```
- (void) initialiseGame
{
    bool gameCreated = FALSE;
    while (!gameCreated)
    {
        gameCreated = [theGame makeGame:@"ptl"];
    }
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
    [loading setText:@"Tap to Start"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setLabels) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

(Note: the performSelector afterDelay is used to allow the view to update before continuing.  Bit of a hack but I couldn't work out a better way!)

The app then loads the game, and when the user taps the screen to start, the next method which is called from the view controller is:

```
- (void) setupLink
{
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<[theGame.theLink length]; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It is on this reference to `theGame.theLink` where I'm am getting the crash.

What has me most confused is that if I call `theGame.theLink` from inside the `initialiseGame` method, it is displays correctly, and also calling any other variable from the `Game` class (such as `thePath` or `theArray` works perfectly, so `theGame` object has not been deallocated in it's entirety, only the variable `theLink`.

It seems to me that the variable is being deallocated somewhere as the view controller is being updated.  I haven't released the variable, and can't work out why only this variable is being deallocated.  As I said at the start, memory-management is not my strength!

Any help/ideas would be hugely appreciated.  Let me know if you require any more details.

Thanks heaps,
Andrew

EDIT:  Setting of `theLink` within `makeGame`

```
- (bool) makeGame:(NSString*)gameType
{
    ...
    [self getLink];
}

- (void) getLink
{
    ...

    if (... && ((arc4random() % 10) > 8))
    {
        theLink = @"Animals";
    }
}
```

There are many different ways `theLink` may be set, depending on random numbers and other factors.  This is the most basic form which simply sets it to a static string.  It doesn't matter how `theLink` is set or what it is set to, the program always crashes at the same point.

Comment: Is there any reason you are doing manual memory management instead of ARC?  This type of issue is less common when using ARC.

Comment: there are no enough code.when do you invoke initialiseGame? when do you invode setupLink? it seems that the theGame is deallocated, but no theGame.theLink.

Comment: Even though this wont influence your current issue, you still should use the `copy` attribute for mutable instance variables.

Comment: Simon - basically because I'm not familiar with it!  I'll check it out, it may solve my issue.

I've included the code I think is relevant.  initialiseGame is invoked from -(void)viewDidLoad, while setupLink is invoked upon user interaction.  I can't see the issue being in either of these places.

Comment: Simon, you're a champion!  Converting to ARC seems to have sorted out the issue.  I was a bit concerned as there's a lot of my dodgy coding which has gone into this so I was expecting changing techniques to be a harrowing experience but it was amazingly easy!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If theLink is being set to the parameter being passed to it ,@"ptl" or some similar temporary string, it will give you a problem, because it is just a pointer pointing at the current location that is holding @"ptl".  After the makeGame method is completed, your system will assume that it is all done with @"ptl" and just free it up.

When you make an @"stringwhatever" in  your code, it is supposed to be the equivalent of making an NSObject that is an immutable literal instance of @"stringwhataver".  It should, in theory handle all the reference counting in a nice way, but when you are doing your own memory management, there are so many ways to lose count of your references.

Comment: theLink is set programatically within the makeGame method.  What it's set to depends on the parameter being passed, but does not include the parameter itself.  I didn't post the code as there are many different ways theLink can be set within makeGame.  I try to post the most relevant sections.

Comment: When theLink is the thing whose reference is getting lost, I think that how it is getting set is probably the most relevant code you have.

Comment: What I don't understand is why I can reference theLink within the method which calls makeGame, but not from outside that method.  I would have thought if the system was going to deallocate the memory it would happen after makeGame is completed not after the method _containing_ makeGame is completed?

Comment: The system will deallocate the memory at its leisure.  Also, what happens to the stack when you leave your method?  It changes quite a bit.  So if your allocation was some weak  creation that only was living on the stack, its a goner.

Comment: Fair point - I've added the code above where theLink is set.  This is where my inexperience comes back to haunt me.  Can you direct me as to how I should be creating a more robust variable which doesn't live on the stack?

Comment: I've just converted to ARC and it seems to have sorted out the issue (for now, at least!).  Thanks a lot for your help, I know this is an area I need to learn a lot more about, but this is just a hobby for me so it's not particularly high on my to-do list!!  Cheers.

Comment: Nice choice with ARC.  That is a great move.  I haven't seen a bug in our apps like this in over a year with ARC, and I used to see them pretty regularly before.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty simple rule to follow. If you've declared properties, *access them via the property*. To do otherwise (as you are doing above, with `theLink = ...`) bypasses all of the memory management built into the property accessors.

```
self.theLink = ...
```

Would have solved this problem under MRC. Switching to ARC has "solved" your problem without you understanding the root cause.